# How to append a 1 to the end of each single digit element within an array, list, or dataframe in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, append, dataframe

I found it difficult to do this with an array, but whatever output method is fine with me. 
I want to take a column from my DataFrame which has single digits numbers and double digits numbers.
The items are currently integers, but they can be converted to `str` or `bool`, whatever necessary to do the task.

I want to add a `1` to the end of all the single digits for example, if the first digit is `2`, then I want it to return `21`.

Lastly, once these operations are complete, I need to split the digits in half and create two columns. 
For example

```
col['a'] = [3, 22, 23, 2, 1]
```

so my output should look like:

```
col['a'] = [31, 22, 23, 21, 11]
```

then, I will most likely do something like

```
col['b'] = col['a'][0:] 
[3,2,2,2,1]
```

and

```
col['c'] = col['a'][:1] 
[1,2,3,1,1].
```

Comment: You should use a string array and find the length of each string. if len(variable) < 2 then variable+"1"

Comment: Sorry are all your elements single digits and all are ints?

Comment: @ FirebladeDan yeah that was my original intent, but I didn't seem to workout as I thought.

Comment: @ EdChum no, they are all integers, but I can convert them to any other dtype.  Currently they are single digits and double digits, I want to add a 1 to the end of all the single digits to make all the number double digits.  The 1 represents a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> df
    a
0   3
1  22
2  23
3   2
4   1

df['aa'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a']*10+1 if 0<=row['a']<=9 else row['a'], axis=1)

>>> df
    a  aa
0   3  31
1  22  22
2  23  23
3   2  21
4   1  11

df['b'] = df.apply(lambda row: divmod(row['aa'], 10)[0], axis=1)
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: divmod(row['aa'], 10)[1], axis=1)

>>> df
    a  aa  b  c
0   3  31  3  1
1  22  22  2  2
2  23  23  2  3
3   2  21  2  1
4   1  11  1  1
```

Comment: probably easier to multiply by 10 and add one than to cast to string, concat a "1", and re-cast to int :)

Comment: True. Changed to multiplying  by 10 and adding 1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is numeric. You can use `np.mod(data, 10)` to get the very last digit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ===========================
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [31, 22, 23, 21, 11]})
df.dtypes

a    int64
dtype: object


# processing
# =====================================
df['c'] = np.mod(df.a, 10)

df
    a  c
0  31  1
1  22  2
2  23  3
3  21  1
4  11  1
```

### Edit:

To add 1 to the end of each single digit number:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [31,22,23,21,11,1,2,3,4,5]})

df

    a
0  31
1  22
2  23
3  21
4  11
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   4
9   5


single_digit_selector = df.a - np.mod(df.a, 10) == 0
df[single_digit_selector] = df[single_digit_selector] * 10 + 1
df

    a
0  31
1  22
2  23
3  21
4  11
5  11
6  21
7  31
8  41
9  51
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work to retrieve the last digit.  I have to convert all the single digits to double digits ending in 1 first though

Comment: @rsotommx I've edited my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: God, the more I see np and pd answers here, the more determined I am to actually go and find something to make with this so I can learn it

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
single_digit = col.a < 10
col['b'] = col.a.where(single_digit, col.a.values / 10)
col['c'] = np.where(single_digit, 1, np.mod(col.a, 10))
```

So if a < 10, b is simply a and the result of integer division by 10 otherwise. Note that numpy arrays support integer division whereas pandas Series don't (as far as I know) which is why I have `col.a.values / 10`. For column c we have 1 if a < 10 and the a mod 10 otherwise.